# Remove all sheets from paper towel roll

Tags: mechanical-engineering

I need to remove all the sheets from a roll of paper towel (about 30 rolls) without damaging the sheets. Is there a faster way than just tearing off one sheet at a time by hand? Goal is to have a pile of individual sheets. This is for white paper towel rolls that have tearable edges.

Comment: Yes, there may be many ways to accomplish your objective. Consider to edit your question with additional information representing your restrictions, resources and any other conditions which might be useful.

Comment: what does `damage` mean in your situation? ... why do you want to do this?

Comment: Wind them onto another roll. Paper mills do this.

Comment: Are you after individual sheets? Do you have the space to unroll everything at once?

Comment: Well, for just 30 rolls, building something is likely out, which leaves you with improvements to the technique.